# Top value of salary form employees in every country SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

This is my database:

- Table Country: id integer (pk), varchar name,
- Table Employe: id integer (pk), countryid integer(fk), varchar name, integer salary.

I want to display employees with the highest salary in every country, but I can display only one employer with the highest salary.

This is my SQL query:

```
Select * 
from Employe 
order by Employe.salary 
desc LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres you can use the comfortable `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (c.name) c.name country, e.name employe, salary
from employe e
join countries c on c.id = e.country_id
order by c.name, salary desc
```

Comment: And this version uses index intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT Employe.countryid , Max(Employe.salary) from Employe GROUP BY  Employe.countryid
```

Comment: Of course she probably will also want to join to the country table to get the country name.

Comment: thanks works. but what if i would like to display top five employees from every country? I can't use max().

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `rank` window function to get the "first" employee[s] (salary-wise) per country:

```
SELECT id, c.name, e.name, salary
FROM   (SELECT id, countryid, name, salary, 
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY countryid ORDER BY salary DESC) rk
        FROM   employee) e
JOIN   country c ON c.id = e.countryid
WHERE  rk = 1
```